# Is it possible to add list of object to change state of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Is it possible to change Entity List state in EF6

```
List<AuditTrail> auditLogs = new List<AuditTrail>();
auditLogs = GetLog(context, CreatedBy);
context.AuditTrails.AddRange(auditLogs);
context.Entry(context.AuditTrails).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
```

It Throws below exception.

```
The entity type DbSet`1 is not part of the model for the current context.
```

How i can achieve above logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can apply change state for every element using linq [ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<AuditTrail> auditLogs = new List<AuditTrail>();
auditLogs = GetLog(context, CreatedBy);
context.AuditTrails.AddRange(auditLogs);
auditLogs.ForEach(l => context.Entry(l).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged);
```

Note that you setting state to `Unchanged`. Don't you want set state to `Changed`?